# load() - doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

Here is the solution of the problem. Thanks to all, and special thanks to Alessandro G. for the private help.

I made load() on jsp URL thinking to load the elaboration with permutation.
The right way is to do load() on the SERVLET URL, passing parameterized data from the form. load() does a GET with data to java servlet, the java servlet elaborates the permutation and his response contain the jsp used as template to print the HTML code with permutations

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        console.log("submit effettuato");

        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(formData);

        $("#aggiornare").load( "anagrammiajax", formData , function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="success"){
                alert("contenuto esterno cariato correttamente");
            }
            if(statusTxt=="error"){
                alert("error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i'm studing web application and i'm trying to create an application to display permutations of a string.

1. I use an html page called "index.html" with a form that send the word to servlet
2. the servelt is called "anagrammiajax" and it works correctly
3. the servlet elaborates the permutations ad dispatch them to jsp page called "anagrammi-     partial.jsp
4. the jsp page just use a foreach to print all the permutations
5. i want use ajax load() method in the index.html page to show into a div the content of the jsp page

problems:

1. i don't want a redirect to jsp page after servlet elaboration, but i wont show again the idex.html wht the updated div (maybe with another redirect from jsp to index.html and adding a setInterval method to auto refresh the page with a timer and load the content?)
2. the jquery load() method don't load the content in the div from jsp page (the permutations printed by forEach) and it returns me a 0 error

please, help me to resolve it and

here is my code:

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Anagrammi su JSP usando JSTL, jQuery, AJAX</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="update.js"></script>   
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Anagrammi su JSP usando JSTL, jQuery e AJAX</h1>
    <p>visualizza gli anagrammi (permutazioni) della parola inserita</p>
    <div>
        <form action="anagrammiajax" name="anagrammi" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="parola">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="genera anagrammi">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Risultati</h2>
        <h3>pagina aggiornata con AJAX e jQuery</h3>
        <div id="aggiornare">
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

update.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    alert("click");
        $("#aggiornare").load("anagrammi-partial.jsp", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
           if(statusTxt=="success"){
            alert("contenuto esterno cariato correttamente");
            }
            if(statusTxt=="error"){
            alert("error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

here is the servlet code:

```
package anagrammiAjax;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AnagrammiAjaxServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        String parola = req.getParameter("parola");
        parola = parola.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(parola);

        ArrayList<String> anagrammi = permutations(parola);
        for(int i=0; i<=anagrammi.size()-1; i++){
            System.out.println(anagrammi.get(i));
        }
        req.setAttribute("parola", parola);
        req.setAttribute("anagrammi", anagrammi);

        try {
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/anagrammi-partial.jsp").include(req, resp);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static ArrayList<String> permutations(String s) {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        permutation(s.toCharArray(), 0, ret);
        return ret;
    }

    public static void permutation(char[] arr, int pos, ArrayList<String> list){
        if(arr.length - pos == 1)
            list.add(new String(arr));
        else
            for(int i = pos; i < arr.length; i++){
                swap(arr, pos, i);
                permutation(arr, pos+1, list);
                swap(arr, pos, i);
            }
    }

    public static void swap(char[] arr, int pos1, int pos2){
        char h = arr[pos1];
        arr[pos1] = arr[pos2];
        arr[pos2] = h;
    }
}
```

and in the end the jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
        <c:forEach items="${anagrammi }" var="indice">
            <c:out value="${indice}"/>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: The problem is that your `load()` function is not actually passing the form data through.  It's simply telling that jsp page to load, and the page can't load without the data that the corresponding controller is expecting. Forms are usually designed for passing data through and loading a different page.  You could use jQuery to send an AJAX request with `parola` inside the request.  I don't know enough about jsp to answer more clearly, though.

Comment: I love Title **load() - doesn't load** XD

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the Ajax request when the user clicks on a submit button.

The JavaScript runs, then the form is submitted, a new page loads and the execution environment for the JavaScript goes away and is a replaced by a new one.

You need to stop the form from submitting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    // Capture the event object in an argument
    $("#submit").click(function(evt) {
    // Prevent the default action
    evt.preventDefault();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I've tried this code:

(' $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert("click");
  $("#aggiornare").load("test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
   if(statusTxt=="success"){
       alert("contenuto esterno cariato correttamente");
      }
      if(statusTxt=="error"){
       alert("error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
      }
  });
 });
}); ')

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code, and use "console.log" and browser's devtools instead of "alert" for debugging

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        console.log("submit form");
        event.preventDefault();
        var thisForm = $(this);

        var jqxhr = $.post("anagrammi-partial.jsp", thisForm.serialize())
        .done(function(data){
            console.log("contenuto esterno caricato correttamente");
            $("#aggiornare").html(data);
            })
        .fail(function(xhr, textStatus){
            console.log("error: "+textStatus );
            })
        .always(function(){
            console.log("finished");
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Your solution might work but doesn't answer the question on `load()`. When using `load()` to avoid redirection, you must use load as a simple request like `load("anagrammiajax?parola="+parola)`. The you action will be perform like if it was a classic form submission but instead of redirecting, the result will be "loaded" wherever you want.

Comment: Why have you rewritten the entire thing (without any explanation) instead of dealing with the specific problem in the question?

Comment: @Quentin cause i presume $.post / $.ajax is better to use instead of .load for someone that want to learn how ajax calls works.

Comment: why -1? my solution might work, I wanted to help him :/

Comment: It rewrites a bunch of stuff that already worked, and doesn't explain which of the many changes actually solves the problem.